# Maven Plugin Surefire no accepting outputDirectory

Tags: maven, surefire

In Maven pom tried to have a single profile only for tests and their reports. Also all test related reports should end up in a single folder per project.
Acording to the documentation this should do the trick

```
    <profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>integration</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>integration</name>
            </property>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.18.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>**/*$*</exclude>
                            <exclude>**/*_closure*</exclude>
                            <exclude>**/support/**</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                        <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/reports</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Still all reports end up in ..\target\surefire-reports. Any idea why the ouputDirectory settings doesn't work

Comment: `<outputDirectory>` is misplaced, it should be under `<configuration>`.

Comment: changed also in the question...still, doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation you have to use the [reportsDirectory](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#reportsDirectory) instead of `outputDirectory` which does not exist.

Comment: on this side they say differently [link](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-report-plugin/examples/report-custom-location.html)...however reportsDirectory works...very odd but Thanks !

Comment: The problem is that you are mistaken [maven-surefire-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/) and [maven-surefire-report-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-report-plugin/)..